# Why is the given binary tree constructed with empty node?

Tags: python, list, tree, binary, representation

I have started to read about the trees structures and binary tree comes the first.

I use the following resource: https://runestone.academy/runestone/static/pythonds/Trees/ListofListsRepresentation.html

There you can find the binary tree image:

[image]

With the list of list representation it looks like:

[image]

**And my questions are**: why do we need the empty node marked with arrow, if it is not displayed on the binary tree image? As we know the binary tree can have **up to** two nodes, so, why do we need this empty node? How does this empty node help us? Or it's just the convention which we should use?

Comment: Seems to be an implementation choice. The arrowed list seems to be a place holder for the right child of C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly explained in the link, specifically with the constructor function:

```
def BinaryTree(r):
  return [r, [], []]
```

When a new leaf is created, it always contains:

- The value itself
- The left node
- The right node

This has the advantage that when you parse the tree, you do not have to check if `left` and `right` exist, as they always exist. This makes the code more regular and simple.